# zeitgeist-extension-fts cant seem to install after upgrade from 10.04 to 10.10

Tags: 10.10, 10.04, unity, upgrade

Okay folks, hope all is well in which ever part of the world you are in, I seem to be having a bit of an issue with unity-place-applications & unity-place-files.

I have just updated from 10.04 to 10.10 trying to take baby steps on my way to natty anyways the offending party seems to be a dependency which is zeitgeist-fts-extension an attempt to correct things with

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

/

```
sudo apt-get install zeitgeist-fts-extension -f
```

doesn't work, I have attempted to use software center, synaptic and all the terminal knowledge I can master but alas I keep getting the error:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  zeitgeist-fts-extension
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0B/9,280B of archives.
After this operation, 86.0kB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 289477 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking zeitgeist-fts-extension (from .../zeitgeist-fts-extension_0.0.6-0ubuntu1_all.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/zeitgeist-fts-extension_0.0.6-0ubuntu1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/zeitgeist/_zeitgeist/engine/extensions/fts.py', which is also in package zeitgeist-extension-fts 0.0.1~bzr20100717-0ubuntu1~ppa1~lucid
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/zeitgeist-fts-extension_0.0.6-0ubuntu1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Now I see a reference to lucid though a quick check with my sources list reveals that all seems well and only maverick is in charge of things.
/*cant post sources.list too much html hyperlinks */

Now I am at a loss because I cannot fix this and would really like to so I can move on and try out some other stuff any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks :)

Buyo

Answer (score 1):

The error message says you are trying to install a "lucid" package although you have upgraded to maverick.

Sometimes you can do this, but it isnt recommended - in this case, it doesnt look like you can.

The ppa you are trying to install from - can you supply a link in your question.

In the interim, comment out the ppa in your software sources.

then run

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

to tidy up your package manager.

Comment: Aah after some wrestling with my laptop I finally found the problem.  My sources list was fine the problem was with zeitgeist-fts-extension & Zeitgeist-extension-fts. One of the two was an older package that seemingly got install and the newer version couldn't overwrite the old one.  So I sudo synaptic in the terminal and managed to removed the obsolete version installed the correct version and now I am officially rocking! :) Will try out 10.10 for a while then upgrade it also! :)

Comment: @devicehandler please answer your own question and Mark as answered